# Exporting SQL to multiple parts

Tags: sql, export

Is there a good way to concurrently export standard ANSI SQL to multiple parts? I'd like to run n queries in parallel to extract a SQL table. I read that using LIMIT / OFFSET is a bad solution since it requires sequentially counting up to the OFFSET, which causes terrible performance for high row count.

Comment: ANSI SQL has FETCH FIRST, not LIMIT.

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page